# bad formatted logging message; the log record have been written to the log

Tags: python, logging, format

I have tried to use the logging module in my application; after reading the documenat I have write the fullowing code:

```
class mainwin():
    def start_logging(self , level):

        logger = logging.getLogger('Rockdome:')
        FORMAT = "***\n\n%s%(name)s [%(levelname)s]\nmodule: %(module)s\nMessage:%(message)s\n***"
        logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, filename= "example.log" , filemode="w")
        logger.setLevel(level)
        self.logger = logger

   def __init__(self ):
       self.start_logging(logging.INFO)        
       self.pid = os.getpid()
       with open('%s/.aria2/pid'%self.home , 'w') as p:
           p.write(str(self.pid))
```

I get the following:

```
***{'threadName': 'MainThread', 'name': 'Rockdome:', 'thread': -1221756160, 'created': 1412549164.939926, 'process': 7195, 'processName': 'MainProcess', 'args': (), 'module': 'mainwin', 'filename': 'mainwin.py', 'levelno': 20, 'exc_text': None, 'pathname': 'mainwin.py', 'lineno': 184, 'msg': 'Application started PID= 7195', 'exc_info': None, 'message': 'Application started PID= 7195', 'funcName': '__init__', 'relativeCreated': 178.4038543701172, 'levelname': 'INFO', 'msecs': 939.9259090423584}Rockdome: [INFO] 
module: mainwin
Message:Application started PID= 7195
***
```

the text between `{}` is the logrecord object itself.

Why the logrecord object have been written to logfile??

The question is : How to get this output??

```
***
Rockdome: [INFO] 
module: mainwin
Message:Application started PID= 7195
***
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have an extra `\n%s` in the beginning of your format string. Remove them:

```
FORMAT = "***\n%(name)s [%(levelname)s]\nmodule: %(module)s\nMessage:%(message)s\n***"
```

Once you do that, you'll get the correct format. That extra `%s` in particular makes all the possible `logger` attributes print, which is why your message looked so far off from what you wanted. You can get a better idea of exactly what happened there with a little test:

```
>>> d = {"test" : "abcdefg", "another" : "asdfasdf"}
>>> print "%(test)s" % d # What you wanted to do
abcdefg
>>> print "%s" % d # What you ended up doing
{'test': 'abcdefg', 'another': 'asdfasdf'}
```